# Special keys with barrier in Ubuntu client

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I have Barrier installed on a macOS server and a Ubuntu client. I use a Belgian keyboard (AZERTY) layout. Most of my keys work just fine (the 'normal' keys: letters and most of the symbols) on the client. But on my Mac, I can type alt-shift-5 for [ and alt-5 for {, but I can't type them on the Ubuntu Client. Another problem is the < and > key, they also don't work.

I previously used Windows as a client and I had the same problems there, but I could use PowerToys to remap those keys and keycombinations.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!